# How to add an image to a custom url?

Tags: images, urls

how can I create a custom URL for my WordPress site and add an image there?

For instance, if my site is www.incrediblesite.com, how can I insert an image into www.incrediblesite.com/images/incredibleimage.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Upload an image to the Media Library like usual.

Go into Settings > Media and untick the box that says:

> Organise my uploads into month- and year-based folders

Then add the following line to your wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'images/'.'files' );
```